# How to use SQL Server database in C# to be shared over a network

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a C# application designed to share a SQL Server database over a network. The server is installed on my PC, and the application is to be deployed to another pc. The connection string I use is as follows:

```
Data Source=Elias\\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword; Secured connection:true;
```

Comment: In Data Source use server IP instead of 'Elias\SqlExpress'

Comment: You don't need a userID and Password if you are using Secured Connection.  It uses a windows credential.  The two computers have to be in the same group and the user credential have to allow access to the database.  So in SQL Server the database must specify a Window Credential.  I usually create a group account and add the user(s) to the group account on both PCs.

Comment: crai : You are wrong.  You can use either the Computer name or IP.

Comment: Correct, you can connect using Computer name, I stand corrected.
Additionally, ensure this option is checked
`Right Click on Server -> Properties -> Connections -> Allow remote connections to this server `

Comment: Since this is a SQL Server **Express** edition, you will also have to **explicitly allow** remote connections - those are *not permitted* by default - see [this post for details on how to do this](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/)

Answer (score 0):

to test a connection string you can use a `.udl` file. Create in your desktop a file **(right clic -> new-> .txt)** and save it like  **.udl extension**. Now open it and you can configure a connection with differents parameters, and you can test it!.

when you finish the test if you open that `.udl` file with `notepad` you get the connection string.

hope this help!